# How to Use Scott Kellum's Parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax

I've been looking all over the Internet for a tutorial on using the Scott Kellum's parallax technique, but didn't find any. I've seen his example on CodePen and for the life of me couldn't figure out how to position and size elements on the page properly.

Let's say that I have a few simple sections as follows:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
<div id="section4"></div>
```

Inside each section I have some content (could be any HTML). How would I go about using Kellum's technique to make backgrounds "overlap"? I'm looking for a tutorial on actually using the technique. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is not a very good answer, but if you want a fairly simple way of doing parallax check out skrollr. All you have to do is link the source and initialize it, and after that it is as simple as adding parameters to your elements. Also there is a very good tutorial if you just search skrollr on Google it will be one of the top hits.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of JavaScript due to performance issues described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6TXuXV1bbY)